# RadMaskedTextBox lost value after postback

Tags: asp.net, telerik, html-select

I have a RadMaskedTextBox in a webpage with an asp:DropDownList that has `autopostback='True'`
and OnSelectedIndexChanged event.  When OnSelectedIndexChanged  fires, the RadMaskedTextBox lost its value.

How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: Do you set the RadMaskedTextBox value in the Page_Load event? If yes, you need not to set it again when the postback occurs.

Comment: in page load i set the mask

Comment: Try to set the value only when it is not a postback e.g. if (!this.IsPostBack) { ... }

Comment: it is like you mentioned

Comment: I can't think of something else. Maybe you could post some code

Comment: Please post your code.  Also please try setting the mask in the markup, instead of code, and see if it works.